# Getting error for savechangeasync()?

Tags: c#

'proEntities' does not contain a definition for 'SaveChangesAsync' and no extension method 'SaveChangesAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'proEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (proEntities db = new proEntities())
        {
            mypic prjt = new mypic() { filename = filename ,data = ConvertImageToBinary(pictureBox1.Image)};
            db.mypics.Add(prjt);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            MessageBox.Show("successfully saved.", "message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWI0o.jpg

Comment: What does proEntities look like? Is it extending from the Entity Framework DbContext?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: @StephenPorter no

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm using EF6.1

Comment: @dayeshnaikmamlekar Before continuing, I guess I should ask... are you going code first or DB first and are you using an edmx file or implementing the entities and contexts yourself with data annotations? It would also still help us a lot to know what proEntities looks like

Comment: @StephenPorter i used DB first and using edmx file.